# if clause in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a code segment in ASP.net MVC2 like this:

```
<% if (Model.EnrollmentNumber.Equals("Global"))
{ %>
  <div id="div1" class="slidingDiv" style="display:none;">
<% }%> 
<% else
{ %>
  <div id="div1" class="slidingDiv" style="display: inline;">                        
<%} %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EnteredEnrollmentNumber)%>
</div>
```

That's, if Model.EnrollmentNum is "Global", then the div is hidden. Else, the div is visible. But the above code has errors. The compiler says "Element div is missing its closing tag"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the compiler doesn't understand the `<% if` tags, and sees two opening `<div` for one closing `</div>`.

You can either just ignore it, or otherwise use the same if statement around your closing tag:

```
<% if (Model.EnrollmentNumber.Equals("Global"))
{ %>
  </div>
<% }%> 
<% else
{ %>
  </div>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not understand that only one of the divs is written. Why not use an asp:Panel instead? In my opinion this is a cleaner solution:

```
<asp:Panel ID="div1" cssclass="slidingDiv" Visible='<%# !Model.EnrollmentNumber.Equals("Global") %>'>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EnteredEnrollmentNumber)%>
</asp:Panel>
```